# The await expression can only be used in an async function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I pass the data through a web socket, and then write this data to the variable "weightSO". Everything works as it should. But I want to add a decryption feature. That is, the data comes, I decrypt them, and display. But there was a problem in the line "weightRT = await FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString (weightSO, key);". Problem "The await expression can only be used in an async function. Try marking the body function with either 'async' or 'async *'." (After encryption I will already display the data of the variable weightRT). And I can't solve this problem with this mistake, I will be grateful for the help.

```
     socketData() async {
        Socket socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.0.1', 4005);
        print('connected');


        // send 0
        socket.add(utf8.encode('0'));
        socket.listen((List<int> event)  {

          setState(()  {
            weightSO = utf8.decode(event);
            
            // data decryption
            var key = '11111';
            weightRT = await  FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString(weightSO, key);

     });

          print(utf8.decode(event));
        });
        weightRT = await FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString(utf8.decode(event), key);
        socket.add(utf8.encode('0'));
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 300));
        socket.close();
      }

    }
```

My Widget:

```html
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 35.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  disabledColor: Colors.pink,
                  textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Text('Weight', textScaleFactor: 2),
                  onPressed:
                  getWeight,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Container(
              child: Text(('$weightSO' ), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0.0, 0, 20.0),
            ),
           
          ]),

    );
  }
```

Comment: you can also make your listen async and can put it await so its will easily take await

Comment: @MuhammadArbazZafar how exactly ??, I'm just a beginner, and did not quite understand what we mean. I tried so, but it didn't help. "setState () async {"

Comment: and remove your setstate there you no need to put setstate

Comment: @MuhammadArbazZafar if I delete this, the data I display in the widget in the variable "weightSO" will not be updated

Comment: @MuhammadArbazZafar I changed my question, added a widget where I display the data

Comment: `socket.transform(utf8.decoder).asyncMap((weightSO) => FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString(weightSO, key))` - this decodes your raw data to `utf8` and then calls decryption - you can use it as a `Stream` in `StreamBuilder`, for more refer to [Converters and codecs](https://dart.dev/articles/archive/converters-and-codecs) and [Asynchronous programming: Streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)

Comment: @pskink I copied this code, but I had an error, could you show it by example, thank you)

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: @pskink if you insert the code like this: "socket.listen (List <int> event) {
       socket.transform (utf8.decoder) .asyncMap (weightSO) => FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString (weightSO, key));
     }); ". The error in" (utf8.decoder) "(The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer <Uint8List, dynamic>'.)

Comment: you dont need any `listen` method just use `var myStream = socket.transform(...);` and you can use it in `StreamBuilder` like `StreamBuilder(stream: myStream, builder: <your builder code>)`

Comment: @pskink still this error in "utf8.decoder"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do but if you just want to update your UI to use `weightSO` value when you get it and use `weightRT` later somewhere in your code then just move the `FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString()` function outside `seState`

Comment: I want the data received through web sockets, to decrypt and show in real time in a variable weightRT (that is in a widget already I will show only a variable weightRT). Before that I simply showed the data encrypted in real time (in a variable "weightSO")

Comment: To update the UI to use weightRT after it's value is calculated just do it before setting state `weightSO = utf8.decode(event);         
// data decryption
var key = '11111';
weightRT = await  FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString(weightSO, key);
setState(()  {  });`

Comment: Thank you, but the mistake with " await   " I still have .In the line "weightRT = await FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.decryptString (weightSO, key);". Problem "The await expression can only be used in an async function. Try marking the body function with either 'async' or 'async *'."

Comment: I'm not sure if we can do this but try making the listen function async   `socket.listen((List<int> event)  async { ...`